# Ansible Dynamic Inventory: Auto-incrementing Integer Assignment to Hostvars

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I have a list of three hosts in a dynamic inventory (ec2.py). I want to assign an auto-incrementing integer to a hostvar of each. For example, the first EC2 instance would get a hostvar `foo=1`, the second would get `foo=2`, and the third `foo=3`. Does anyone have any idea how to do that? I've looked at loops and the "set_fact" module, but I can't quite figure out how to do it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with any task or construct inside Ansible playbooks, since all this pretty much does run *per host* and in each loop you do not know about the state of the other hosts.

I think your best bet would be to create a modified version of the [`ec2.py`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/plugins/inventory/ec2.py) and just increment a global var there. I never used the `ec2.py` but it appears the function `get_host_info_dict_from_instance()` is where the `host_vars` are collected. You should be able to inject your counter var there.

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be the answer.